# Реализация корзины для интернет-магазина

Tags: php, javascript, frontend

Всем привет. Делаю интернет-магазин, возник вопрос с реализацией корзины. В голове лишь 1 вариант, как это сделать, но хочется все-таки услышать мнение со стороны.

Идея реализации: хранить все данные в массиве в $_COOKIE, т.е. каждое действие с корзиной делает AJAX-запрос к серверу с id товара и действием (удаление, добавление).

Сразу скажу, реализация фронт-энда на jQuery идет, ничего сложного нет, чтобы юзать vue/react и т.д..

Корзина будет доступна на каждой странице, также будет возможность изменять количество товара и удалять товар из корзины, с этим больше всего трудностей.

Также хочется поинтересоваться, как правильно изменять общую цену товаров в корзине? Добавлять к каждому товару атрибут data-price, а затем делать подсчет через цикл по каждому товару, считая сумму? Или же лучше делать запрос к серверу после каждого изменения?

Answer (score 3):

Намного проще в Cookies хранить только номер сессии пользователя и токен (для проверки), а сами данные о заказе хранить в БД. В этом случае мы обращаемся к БД по номеру сессии и запрашиваем список заказанных товаров с их ценами (например, из таблицы cart_products). Общее количество товаров и сумму к оплате также считаем в цикле на сервере.

В этом случае изменение содержимого корзины осуществляется через AJAX-запросы к серверу, где при добавлении нового товара мы указываем добавляемый product_id (в базе ищется соответствующий продукт, а в таблицу с заказанными товарами добавляются нужные поля - id, название, цена и т.д.), а при удалении - соответственно удаляемый product_id (то же самое делается с артикулами, если под одним product_id у вас несколько позиций).

При выводе краткой информации о содержимом корзины (для всех страниц сайта) можно при сборке страницы запрашивать саму таблицу cart_products, либо хранить краткую информацию в самой таблице с сессиями пользователей.

P.S. Также желательно добавить код, который периодически будет очищать старые данные из таблицы с сессиями и заказанными товарами (например, те, которые старше 1 недели).

Comment: Хм, интересный вариант, только это получается, что для каждого зашедшего на сайт, мы генерим свой токен и ID сессии, верно? Затем, при каждом обновлении страницы, мы вытаскиваем данные из БД по пользователю?

Comment: И да, т.е. при каждой загрузке страницы, при наличии товаров в корзине, мы запрашиваем у БД актуальную инфу по товарам, а затем уже считаем их стоимость в цикле, верно?

Comment: @Alexxosipov да, все верно. по поводу последнего комментария - написал в ответе отдельный абзац.

Comment: @Alexxosipov если пользователь на сайте новый, то выдаем ему id сессии и выставляем куку (далее проверяем наличие этой куки). также надо не забыть добавить код, который будет периодически очищать старые сессии и старые данные из таблицы заказанных товаров (например, старше 1 недели).

Comment: А как сильно это скажется на нагрузке на сервер? Или это крошки? В среднем, сейчас идет по 500-600 чел. в сутки с рекламы, все они будут идти на ИМ.

Comment: @Alexxosipov это совсем немного. при такой посещаемости будет в среднем по 3-4 тыс. просмотров в сутки и соответственно 500-600 сессий. обычный mysql хорошо держит и выдает таблицы с сессиями до 100+ млн. строк (запрос должен занимать не более 5-10 миллисекунды). для улучшения производительности в таблице с сессиями ищем сессию только по первичному ключу (id), токен уже сверяем после получения строки из базы. если нужно еще улучшить результат - прикручиваем memcached и кэшируем сессии

Comment: Очень плохая идея - пользователю надо зарегистрироваться. Зачем хранить номер сессии и вытягивать по нему из базы если можно сразу сохранять в сессии?

Comment: @JonnyManowar зачем пользователю регистрироваться? сессия в cookie выдается все зависимости зарегистрирован пользователь на сайте или нет. просто проверяется наличие куки с сессией - если ее нет, то выставляем новую, если есть - ищем в базе товары и прочую информацию по этой сессии.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov кстати, а почему сразу в cookie не хранить товары? Для чего в Вашем решении товары хранятся в БД, не излишне ли это?

Comment: @Alexxosipov можно хранить товары и в самих cookies, но данный подход имеет ряд минусов. во-первых, у вас не будет статистики по добавленным, но еще не оформленным товарам (что бывает очень полезно анализировать для увеличения конверсии продаж). во-вторых, возможна рассинхронизация с актуальным ассортиментом (когда информация о товаре добавлена в cookies, а потом этот товар может уйти в архив или быть недоступным для покупки. здесь потребуется дополнительная проверка перед оформлением заказа).

Comment: @Alexxosipov в-третьих, с точки зрения архитектуры на мой взгляд проще сделать именно хранение корзины в БД (при оформлении заказа мы просто переносим товары из таблицы корзины в таблицу заказанных товаров, а не создаем новые записи). также к тем же сессиям при дальнейшем развитии проекта помимо корзины можно привязать регистрацию пользователей, показ определенных баннеров, хранение информации о ранее просмотренных товарах и т.д. в рамках только cookies это будет сложнее логически организовать.

Comment: @Alexxosipov в целом ваш вариант тоже рабочий. только в этом случае надо будет в цикле прогонять заказанные товары, которые хранятся в cookies, чтобы получить их общее количество и сумму заказа